# github api authentication when searching for latest releases

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of repositories, I want to receive the latest release through the github api. The code is working, but the error "HTTPError: rate limit exceeded" periodically appears there. I've read the documentation but don't understand how to do it. There's curl for Linux, but I only have the python interpreter itself.

Please explain how to solve this problem. Please show an example code for the python interpreter.

```
import urllib.request, json

url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/latest'

try:
    u=json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()).get('assets', True)
except:
    print('HTTPError')    

for item in u:
    f = item['browser_download_url']
    ....
```

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50441345/2800348 recommends using https://pypi.org/project/ratelimit/

Comment: I need this for a website, and visitors won't want to wait. I am ready to use it correctly, as they require, only I do not understand how to do it at all.

Comment: Many APIs that limit you allow you to pay money to increase your rate limit, but AFAIK Github does not. Look into caching your responses using https://pypi.org/project/cachier/ or something similar.

Comment: If you have more than one webserver host, consider having them hit a common Redis cache: https://pypi.org/project/redis